# Error when online training a stateful deep LSTM stack

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I would like to use online training with a deep LSTM model.

When using online training, my batch size is 1.

I would also like the model to be stateful.

As such, I don't want my input to be a sequence, but rather a single state. Thus the number of steps in my input is also 1. I would like the model to learn the sequence based on the individual input states

Thus, I've constructed the following model (Tensorflow JS):

```
    this.model = tf.sequential();
    this.model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 256, returnSequences: false, batchInputShape: [1, 1, input_dim], stateful: true }));
    this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: output_dim}));
    this.model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });
    this.model.summary();
```

This model works perfectly fine, however when I want to stack more LSTM layers, for example trying the following model:

```
    this.model = tf.sequential();
    this.model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 256, returnSequences: true, batchInputShape: [1, 1, input_dim], stateful: true }));
    this.model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 128, returnSequences: false}));
    this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: output_dim}));
    this.model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });
```

Above I've changed returnSequences to true in the first LSTM layer so that its output shape can be accepted by the second LSTM layer.

When attempting to fit on the same input and output that works with the first model on the second model, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]`
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: [Check this thread out](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3550).

Comment: Thanks @yudhiesh, looks like a possible bug. Someone even posted a workaround in that thread since the time you commented, and that workaround has worked for me :)